# OpenRasta IoC with Unity 2.0

Tags: openrasta, unity2.0

Does OpenRasta support Unity 2.0 ?
The DI.Unity is build against Unity 1.2

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-unity -- Support for Unity 2.1+ now (Although it has been 9 months since the last answer to this question...)

Answer (score 0):

OpenRasta is a framework for .NET as well as Unity2.0.
I found in documentation that OpenRasta supports Dependency Injection and IoC. So why mix them together?
If you already use Unity as IoC container I don't see any problem to resolve OpenRasta types. They are common types as others.

Comment: we have our own container in unity 2, to resolve our dependency, would like to use it to resolve OR's dependency as well.

Comment: @aeseny OpenRasta by default uses its own implementation of DI container, and it is possible to use custom DI container to resolver everything openrasta need internally. I would like, at the same time, use the same custom container for my own dependency registation. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: As you wrote you already use Unity2.0. So keep using it if you want. One drawback is that your project would have 2 frameworks which support IoC. Do you have any specific problems while using them?